# What happens to user data created during a TestFlight deployment of an iOS app?

Tags: ios, core-data, testflight

I'm building an iOS app that uses the Core Data store to persist user data. I've had trouble finding an explanation of what happens to the Core Data store when:

1. The build expires
2. A new build is released
3. The app is launched and the user installs the app from the App Store rather than TestFlight

Can the Core Data store be used by new builds on TestFlight or the App Store? If not, what do I need to do to allow the user to have seamless access to their data?

Comment: In all cases you describe the app bundle is simply installed over the existing app. Documents/data aren't touched, so they will retain access to any data unless they actually delete the app and data from their device.

Comment: Thanks - that's really helpful! Is there any nuance to how iOS knows to use the same user data? E.g., if you change the build number or if you have the TestFlight build + the released version from the App Store on your phone, will iOS use the same user data for both installations?

Comment: The bundle id is how it identifies the app. If an app with the same bundle id is already present on the device (regardless of how it was installed, App Store, TestFlight, Xcode) then that is where the new install goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User data is pulled based on the bundle id of an app. The bundle id of an app installed from XCode, TestFlight, or the AppStore may be the same; if so, the same core data store will be used. (Thanks to Paulw11 for this answer)